# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on my function

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to make available this function that i found in the web but when i start into the terminal the function is giving to me this error:

```
/home/simone/gekko/strategies/high.js:10
sma: function(name, price, points)
^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I also tried to change the first name of the first item that is request in the function, i changed the "this[name]" but nothing. I'm new to javascript and i want learn/understand what is my fault.
The code:

```
// simple sma function
// params: name-of-array, price (of something), number of points (sma lenght)
// returns: the moving average price/value
sma: function(name, price, points)
   {
       // create arr if not exist + generate array
       if( !this[name] )
              {
           let a = 0,     b = [];
           for (a; a < points; a++) { b[a] = 0; }
           this[name] = b;
       }

       let arr = this[name],
           len = arr.length;

       arr[len] = price; // add new to last in array
       arr.shift(); // remove first (old) from array (keeping max order)
       this[name] = arr; // set/save

       // calculate current average
       let i = 0,
            total = 0;

       for( i; i < len; i++ ) { total += arr[i]; }

       let avg = total / len;
       return avg;
   },
```

all the code:

```
var strat = {

init : function() {

}
//======================================================================================
// simple sma function
// params: name-of-array, price (of something), number of points (sma lenght)
// returns: the moving average price/value
sma: function(name, price, points)
   {
       // create arr if not exist + generate array
       if( !this[name] )
              {
           let a = 0,     b = [];
           for (a; a < points; a++) { b[a] = 0; }
           this[name] = b;
       }

       let arr = this[name],
           len = arr.length;

       arr[len] = price; // add new to last in array
       arr.shift(); // remove first (old) from array (keeping max order)
       this[name] = arr; // set/save

       // calculate current average
       let i = 0,
            total = 0;

       for( i; i < len; i++ ) { total += arr[i]; }

       let avg = total / len;
       return avg;
   },
 };
//======================================================================================

strat.check = function(candle) {

let sma_high = this.sma('sma_high', this.candle.high, 10);
let sma_low = this.sma('sma_low', this.candle.low, 10);

// the rest of your logic, simple sample:
if( sma_high < sma_low ) this.advice('long')
else this.advice('short')
}
//======================================================================================

module.exports = strat;
```

Comment: That function needs to be contained in an object to be valid - can you show more code please?

Comment: The `key: value` notation is only valid in Javascript objects (enclosed in `{}`). For an globally / locally defined function you need to use `var sma = function()` or `function sma()`

Comment: You are missing a comma after `init : function() {

}`

Comment: Check my answer now i added a version of your code fixed and running

Answer (score -1):

So the on runtime the parser doesn't know what `sma` is - that's the meaning of the error you are getting. It doesn't know it since your syntax is invalid.

There are two ways to go about this.

1. sma is an independent function that should be declared like this:

```
function sma(name, price, points){
   // Do stuff
}

const sma = (name, price, points)=>{
  // Do stuff
}

// invoke by calling:
sma("Mercedes", 20000, 50);
```

1. sma is a built in method in some class object:

```
class Foo {
 sma(name, price, points){
    // Do stuff
  }
}

// invoke by calling:
Foo.sma("Mercedes", 20000, 100);
```

here's your code fixed and working:

```
class Strat {

  init(){
  }

  sma(name, price, points) {
       // create arr if not exist + generate array
       if( !this[name] )
              {
           let a = 0,     b = [];
           for (a; a < points; a++) { b[a] = 0; }
           this[name] = b;
       }

       let arr = this[name],
           len = arr.length;

       arr[len] = price; // add new to last in array
       arr.shift(); // remove first (old) from array (keeping max order)
       this[name] = arr; // set/save

       // calculate current average
       let i = 0,
            total = 0;

       for( i; i < len; i++ ) { total += arr[i]; }

       let avg = total / len;
       return avg;
       }
    }
Strat.check = function(candle) {

let sma_high = this.sma('sma_high', this.candle.high, 10);
let sma_low = this.sma('sma_low', this.candle.low, 10);

// the rest of your logic, simple sample:
if( sma_high < sma_low ) this.advice('long')
  else this.advice('short')
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me why is used this[name] and how is it working because on the web i only find this. declaration and not without the dot

Comment: I am not sure about the goals of the function but generally this[name] is set to make sure that a name argument was given. Javascript is pretty open and potentially the sma function could be called without any arguments leaving the name argument empty. If that is the case then the function makes an array itself filled with `0` according to how many points were provided (which is weird since js takes argument by order so if no name was given no price or points were given as well)

Comment: as for the different between `this.name` and `this[name]` the difference is that you cannot use a variable injection with the dot notation. so if `name` is a `var` like `name='foo'` this code: `this.name` would look for `name` in the object/class/function while `this[name]` would look for `foo`.